# Store in a variable the number of rows from a table where a column has a certain value in SQL Server Compact

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, compact-database

I have a Windows Forms application and a SQL Server Compact 3.5 database. I want to store in a variable the number of rows from a table where a column has a certain value. I have something like this to count all the rows from a table:

```
CarsDataSet carsData = new CarsDataSet();
int nrCars = carsData.CarName.Rows.Count;
```

How can I get the information I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you'll want to write your SQL command which returns the number of rows in the query (using the count(*) operator). The where clause of the SQL statement is where you can filter what specific Cars you want (e.g. Model = 'Ford')

```
string sql = "select count(*) from Cars where SomeColumn='{put_your_filter_here}'";
```

Now create a SqlCommand object which we will execute on your SqlCeConnection. You'll need to open a SqlCeConnection to your local Sql Compact Edition database.

```
SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(sql, DbConnection.ceConnection);
```

Execute the command which returns the count(*) number of rows and stores in cars variable

```
int cars = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Use/print the result of the query

```
Console.WriteLine("Number of cars: " + cars);
```

Comment: @Xufox better now?

Comment: @Mangist Far better!

Answer (score 0):

You can get it like this.

```
dcarsData.CarName.Rows.Select("CompanyName Like 'SomeString%'").Count()
```